# Spring boot @Cacheble with Ehcache

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache

I'm using Spring boot with Ehcache for caching some data in the application.
The application is a rest service that caches some data that has high usage.

The code in our controllers looks like:

```
@Cacheable("CategoryModels")
  @GetMapping("/category/{companyId}")
  public List<CategoryViewModel> getAllCategories(@PathVariable(value = "companyId", required = true) long companyId,
    @RequestHeader("user") String user) {
//custom code here
}
```

Now in some situations the users are getting different data sets back from the server. Can someone explain this in the above situation?

If data is changed in the database I refresh the cache and the program will auto update the updated data to the

For refreshing the cache I use a custom written method:

```
Cache categoryCache = (Cache) manager.getCache("CategoryModels").getNativeCache();
categoryCache.removeAll();
categoryController.getAllCategories(company.getCompanyId(), null);
```

I have the same behavior on other caches that are used and refreshed on the same way the above cache is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to parametrize your cache definition with :

```
@Cacheable(value="CategoryModels", key="{ #root.methodName, #companyId, #user.id }")
```

Comment: Then without the #user.id I think. All the users should have the same result and the user id does not used to calculate the result of the method.

Comment: @JimmyD Then you've found your problem. You didn't specify any key, and in that case, Spring automatically generates a key using your method parameters. In this case, these method parameters are user-specific, since you added the `user` parameter to it. If you don't want it, customize the key using the method provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a couple of things. First off the default key resolver that spring provides does not consider anything but the names of the parameters. The cleanest way to fix this kid to write your own key revolver that considers both class and method, without this it could be possible to get back data from a completely different method that happens to share the same parameter list.